# How do I make 'SELECT COUNT(*) from clicks' faster?

Tags: postgresql

I'm using Postgres.

I have queries of the form:

```
`SELECT COUNT(*) from clicks where link_id=1`
```

Clicks is millions of rows.

These queries are taking 10-20 seconds.

Are there any elegant ways to accelerate this?

**Edit: Query plan:**
[image]

**Indexes**

```
CREATE INDEX clicks_link_id_index
    ON public.clicks USING btree
    (link_id ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
CREATE INDEX clicks_link_workspace_id_index
    ON public.clicks USING btree
    (link_workspace_id ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
CREATE INDEX index_date_trunc
    ON public.clicks USING btree
    (date_trunc('day'::text, inserted_at) ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

`SET ENABLE_SEQSCAN TO OFF`:

[image]

Comment: Do you have an index on `link_id`?

Comment: Yes, but it's slow even without the `where`.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: I've updated it with indexes and query plan

Comment: I've noticed that it works OK on my workstation (32gb of RAM), but not on my Google Cloud SQL instance (1.7GB RAM)

Comment: Your shown query does not match your shown EXPLAIN plan.  Have you tried vacuuming the table to promote index-only-scan?

Comment: Might want to take a look at: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Count_estimate

Comment: @jjanes the query is equivalent. All queries of this form are slow. I did try to vacuum it, no effect.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver this isn't a viable solution for the types of queries I need to run unfortunately, but thanks nonetheless! :)

Comment: Can you repeat the EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) query after doing `set enable_seqscan=off;`?  also, turning track_io_timing to on will give more information.  Also, what version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Comment: @jjanes Done, attached above. Thanks!

Comment: if you have little count of link_id's then try to use partial indexes on even partition the table by link_id

Answer (score 0):

It thinks the index-only scan is going to be 4 times cheaper than the sequential scan, so I am confused on why it didn't pick index-only-scan in the first place (before you had set enable_seqscan=off).  Now if you set that back to the default, does it go back to using the seq scan again?

If you freshly VACUUM the table, does it get much faster with the index-only scan?  While 99% of the rows are fetched without heap fetches, the remaining 1% could account for most of the time.

Or maybe you should just throw more hardware at it.  Having more RAM in which to cache data (either in shared_buffers or in filesystem cache) can't hurt.